Set ViewPager2 previous indicator color and indicator width
Is there a way to set the width of indicator and previous indicator color like this example ?

I've tried but only for selected and unselected color and the result is


TabLayout
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/pageIndicator"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
            app:tabGravity="center"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:tabBackground="@drawable/onboarding_selector"/>

onboarding_selector.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/onboarding_selected" android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/onboarding_unselected" />
</selector>

onboarding_selected.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <item android:gravity="center">
        <shape>
            <size
                android:width="@dimen/_50sdp"
                android:height="@dimen/_5sdp" />
            <corners android:radius="@dimen/_500sdp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/primary_900" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>

onboarding_unselected.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <item android:gravity="center">
        <shape>
            <size
                android:width="@dimen/_50sdp"
                android:height="@dimen/_5sdp" />
            <corners android:radius="@dimen/_500sdp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/gray_200" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>

